# Clase claendar Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, calendar

necesito hacer un programa python que mediante una fecha, concretamente el 19 febrero de 2020. obtener que dia de la semana va a caer, es importante que sea mediante el uso de la clase calendar, grácias de antemeno.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`calendar` no es la herramienta apropiada para ello, al menos no directamente. El módulo `calendar` sirve para generar calendarios de meses o años completos (en texto o en html) y no para un día en particular.

Aunque podrías usar `calendar.Calendar().monthdatescalendar(2020,2)` para obtener una lista con las semanas de febrero del 2020, cada una de esas semanas será otra lista cuyos elementos son objetos `datetime.date`. Uno de esos elementos será el día que buscas, `datetime.date(2020,2,19)`, del que podrías sacar el día de la semana con `weekday()`, pero para eso ¿por qué no usar directamente `datetime.date(2020,2,19)` sin necesidad de meter `calendar` de por medio, que sólo complica las cosas?

Esta sería la solución sin usar `calendar`:

```
from datetime import date
print("Dia de la semana:", date(2020, 2, 19).weekday())
```

Obtendrías que el día de la semana es el 2, y sabiendo que el 0 es lunes eso implica que el día en cuestión es miércoles.

Si quieres que el día de la semana salga por su nombre, en lugar de número, puedes preparar una lista con los nombres:

```
nombres_dias_semana = [ 'lunes', 'martes', 'miércoles', 'jueves', 'viernes', 'sábado', 'domingo' ]
fecha = date(2020, 2, 19)
print("El {} es {}.".format(fecha,  nombres_dias_semana[fecha.weekday()]))
```

```
El 2020-02-19 es miércoles.
```

Usando `calendar`, lo que puedes obtener fácilmente es un calendario del mes, así:

```
>>> from calendar import TextCalendar
>>> TextCalendar().prmonth(2020,2)
   February 2020
Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su
                1  2
 3  4  5  6  7  8  9
10 11 12 13 14 15 16
17 18 19 20 21 22 23
24 25 26 27 28 29
```

Pero sacar el día de la semana de un día en particular es mucho más complejo.

La única utilidad que puede tener el módulo `calendar` en todo esto, es que puedes evitarte el definir tu lista con los nombres de los días de la semana, pues el módulo trae una ya definida en `calendar.day_name` que podrías usar en lugar de `nombres_dias_semana`. La lista de `calendar` además se adapta al idioma que tengas fijado en el `locale`, lo que puede ser conveniente si la aplicación ha de ser multilingüe.

Si no es esta la solución que buscabas, edita la pregunta para añadir más detalles y sobre todo el código que has hecho hasta ahora usando `calendar`.

Comment: Ayúdanos a mejorar la calidad en el sitio , sugiriendo a los usuarios mejorar sus preguntas de acuerdo a [ask].

Answer (score 0):

## Día de la semana en Español:

```
import locale
import datetime
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'es_ES') 
fecha = datetime.datetime.now()
print(fecha.isoformat())
print(fecha.strftime("%A %d %B %Y %I:%M"))
```

Resultado: jueves 25 febrero 2021 09:49

PD: si tienes dudas sobre que libreria local instaladas tienes ejecuta el siguiente comoando:

```
locale -a
```